# Load data from sqlite3 into GtkTreeView

Tags: python, sqlite, gtk

I need to load data from a sqlite3 table into a GtkTreeView. Table is something like following:

```
id    display_name    connection_name    directory

1       server1         server1            dir1
2       server2         server2            dir1
3       server1         server1            dir2
4       server2         server2            dir2
```

The result in GtkTreeView should be:

- dir1

  - server1
  - server2
- dir2

  - server1
  - server2

Is it possible? Which kind of sql query i need to retrive data correctly? At the moment i've no problem to load this kind of data from json or xml; but i'd like to load data from sqlite as well.
My problem is the query: i'm not sure how to group result by directory field. I'm trying with

```
GROUP BY
```

method but with no success.
Thanks very much for help.
Bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP BY` is not meant to be used in such case. It is used for aggregate functions.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

You can just use `SELECT * FROM table` then fetch all the results, check the `directory` of each record and put it under corresponding node.